# Find neighbours of a switch using Python and SNMP (LLDP)

Tags: python, python-3.x

### INTRO

[**About SNMP**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-snmp-simple-network-management-protocol)

> **SNMP** stands for simple network management protocol. It is a way that
> servers can share information about their current state, and also a
> channel through which an administer can modify pre-defined values.
> SNMP is a protocol that is implemented on the application layer of the
> networking stack (click here to learn about networking layers). The
> protocol was created as a way of gathering information from very
> different systems in a consistent manner.

You can read more about *SNMP*, *OIDs* and *SNMP methods* in the above link. As a summary, this script uses:

- snmp version 2c
- *snmpwalk* as the main *snmp method* to get the data
- the data fetched from a device is fetched from a specific *OID* (more LLDP OIDs can be found [here](http://www.mibdepot.com/cgi-bin/getmib3.cgi?win=mib_a&i=1&n=LLDP-MIB&r=cisco&f=LLDP-MIB-V1SMI.my&v=v1&t=tree#LldpPortNumber))

[**About LLDP**](https://wiki.wireshark.org/LinkLayerDiscoveryProtocol)

> The Link Layer Discovery Protocol (**LLDP**) is a vendor neutral layer 2
> protocol that can be used by a station attached to a specific LAN
> segment to advertise its identity and capabilities and to also receive
> same from a physically adjacent layer 2 peer.

---

#### Combining SNMP and LLDP using python

The purpose of my program is, by using Python3.6 and provided a file of switches data (community string, snmp port and switch ip), to return the neighbours data (local and remote port + name of the neighbours) for all the switches in the file.

Example config file:

```
community_string1, snmp_port1, ip1
community_string2, snmp_port2, ip2
community_string3, snmp_port3, ip3
```

Example output:

```
[
    {
        "name1": {
            "ip": "ip1",
            "neighbours": [
                {
                    "neighbour_name1": "neighbour_name1",
                    "local_port1": "local_port1",
                    "remote_port1": "remote_port1"
                },
                {
                    "neighbour_name2": "neighbour_name2",
                    "local_port2": "local_port2",
                    "remote_port2": "remote_port2"
                },
                {
                    "neighbour_name3": "neighbour_name3",
                    "local_port3": "local_port3",
                    "remote_port3": "remote_port3"
                },
            ]
        },
        "name2":  {data here},
        "name3":  {data here},
    }
]
```

**Explaining the output**

- `name1` represents the name of the switch from the first line of the config file (which is retrieved by doing a snmp walk for `PARENT_NAME_OID`)
- `ip1` represents the ip of the switch from the first line of the config file (this is taken as is from the config file)
- the neighbours are all retrieved via snmp using specific OIDs (see code below).

I thought this JSON output format is the most relevant but if you have better ideas, I'd like to hear.

---

**The code**

Now, the code is a bit messy but it does its job using the [`pysnmp`](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp) library which can be easily installed via `pip`. It receives the config file as a CLI argument, parses it and the processes the info in it.

```py
"""
Parse a file which contains switches information (community, snmp_port, ip)
and query those devices (neighbours information) via LLDP. Return the data
as a JSON object.
"""

import argparse
import itertools
import pprint
import os
import re

from pysnmp.hlapi import *


NEIGHBOUR_PORT_OID = '1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.8.0'
NEIGHBOUR_NAME_OID = '1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9'
PARENT_NAME_OID = '1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.3.3'


class MissingOidParameter(Exception):
    """
    Custom exception used when the OID is missing.
    """
    pass


def is_file_valid(filepath):
    """
    Check if a file exists or not.

    Args:
        filepath (str): Path to the switches file
    Returns:
        filepath or raise exception if invalid
    """

    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        raise ValueError('Invalid filepath')
    return filepath


def get_cli_arguments():
    """
    Simple command line parser function.
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    parser.add_argument(
        '-f',
        '--file',
        type=is_file_valid,
        help='Path to the switches file'
    )
    return parser


def get_switches_from_file():
    """Return data as a list from a file.

    The file format is the following:

    community_string1, snmp_port1, ip1
    community_string2, snmp_port2, ip2
    community_string3, snmp_port3, ip3

    The output:

    [
        {"community": "community_string1", "snmp_port": "snmp_port1", "ip": "ip1"},
        {"community": "community_string2", "snmp_port": "snmp_port2", "ip": "ip2"},
        {"community": "community_string3", "snmp_port": "snmp_port3", "ip": "ip3"},
    ]
    """

    args = get_cli_arguments().parse_args()
    switches_info = []
    with open(args.file) as switches_info_fp:
        for line in switches_info_fp:
            line = line.rstrip().split(',')
            switches_info.append({
                'community': line[0].strip(),
                'snmp_port': line[1].strip(),
                'ip': line[2].strip(),
            })
    return switches_info


def parse_neighbours_ports_result(result):
    """
    One line of result looks like this:

    result = iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.8.0.2.3 = 2

    Where the last "2" from the OID is the local port and the value
    after '=' is the remote port (2)
    """
    if not result:
        raise MissingOidParameter('No OID provided.')

    value = result.split(' = ')
    if not value:
        return 'Missing entire value for OID={}'.format(result)
    else:
        oid, port = value
        local_port = re.search(r'{}\.(\d+)'.format(NEIGHBOUR_PORT_OID[2:]), oid).group(1)

        if port:
            remote_port = re.search(r'(\d+)', port).group(1)
        else:
            remote_port = 'Unknown'

    return 'local_port', local_port, 'remote_port', remote_port


def parse_parent_name(result):
    """
    One line of result looks like this:

    result = iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.3.3.0 = Switch01

    The name of the parent is "Switch01"
    """

    if not result:
        raise MissingOidParameter('No OID provided.')

    value = result.split(' = ')
    if not value:
        return 'Missing entire value for OID={}'.format(result)
    else:
        return 'Unknown' if not value[-1] else value[-1]


def parse_neighbour_names_results(result):
    """
    One line of result looks like this:

    result = iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9.0.2.3 = HP-2920-24G

    The name of the parent is "Switch01"
    """

    if not result:
        raise MissingOidParameter('No OID provided.')

    value = result.split(' = ')
    if not value:
        return 'Missing entire value for OID={}'.format(result)
    else:
        return ('name', 'Unknown') if not value[-1] else ('name', value[-1])


def main():
    data = {}
    switches_filedata = get_switches_from_file()

    for switch in switches_filedata:
        community = switch.get('community')
        snmp_port = switch.get('snmp_port')
        ip = switch.get('ip')

        name = ''
        for (error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds) in nextCmd(
                SnmpEngine(),
                CommunityData(community),
                UdpTransportTarget((ip, snmp_port)),
                ContextData(),
                ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(PARENT_NAME_OID)),
                lexicographicMode=False
        ):
            # this should always return one result
            name = parse_parent_name(str(var_binds[0]))

        if not name:
            print('Could not retrieve name of switch. Moving to the next one...')
            continue

        neighbour_names = []
        neighbour_local_remote_ports = []

        for (error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds) in nextCmd(
                SnmpEngine(),
                CommunityData(community),
                UdpTransportTarget((ip, snmp_port)),
                ContextData(),
                ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(NEIGHBOUR_NAME_OID)),
                lexicographicMode=False
        ):
            for var_bind in var_binds:
                neighbour_names.append(
                    parse_neighbour_names_results(str(var_bind))
                )

        for (error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds) in nextCmd(
                SnmpEngine(),
                CommunityData(community),
                UdpTransportTarget((ip, snmp_port)),
                ContextData(),
                ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(NEIGHBOUR_PORT_OID)),
                lexicographicMode=False
        ):
            for var_bind in var_binds:
                neighbour_local_remote_ports.append(
                    parse_neighbours_ports_result(str(var_bind))
                )

        neighbours = []
        for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(
            neighbour_names,
            neighbour_local_remote_ports,
            fillvalue='unknown'
        ):
            neighbours.append({
                a[0]: a[1],
                b[0]: b[1],
                b[2]: b[3]
            })

        data[name] = {
            'ip': ip,
            'neighbors': neighbours
        }

    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_data = main()
    pprint.pprint(all_data, indent=4)
```

**What I'm especially looking after:**

- better / more performant ways of using `pysnmp`'s functionality (perhaps I can do only one SNMP walk to store all the data and then from there get the needed data for all the OIDs) - kinda like we're doing when parsing `lxml`s html tree.
- better ways of structuring my code
- improvements regarding the names of the functions/names
- I tried to stick to PEP8 but I didn't really focused on it. I'm familiar with almost everything related to it and so I would like you guys not to focus on this too much.

Comment: *NOTE*: Unless you have access to some switches within a network this can hardly be tested and I'm sorry that I can't provide a test environment where you can play with it. I hope you guys will still have the pleasure to review this ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Type hints

PEP484 type hints will help; an example:

```
def is_file_valid(filepath: str) -> bool:
```

### Function contracts

`is_file_valid` isn't actually what's happening. You're using this function to do two things:

- Cast an input string to whatever the program needs through the argparse system
- Verify that the input string is correct

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#type) shows how this should actually be done:

```
parser.add_argument('bar', type=open)
```

This will call `open` and give you back a file object, or fail if the file doesn't exist.

### Parsing

The `get_switches_from_file` can use tuple unpacking:

```
community, port, ip = (t.strip() for t in line.split(','))
```

This has the added advantage that irregular lines with more than three parts will cause an error rather than being silently ignored.

Better yet, delegate this to a class:

```
class Switch:
    def __init__(self, line: str):
        self.community, self.port, self.ip = (
            field.strip() for field in line.split(',')
        )
```

### Avoid iterative concatenation

Rather than maintaining `switches_info`, simply `yield` each dictionary from the inner loop. This will cause your method to go from O(n) memory to O(1) memory, at a probable slight cost to runtime.

If you use the `Switch` class above, this could look like

```
    args = get_cli_arguments().parse_args()
    with args.file as switches_info_fp:
        for line in switches_info_fp:
            yield Switch(line)
```

### Separation of concerns

`parse_neighbours_ports_result` has an odd return format. It's not clear that the first and third string are useful. Either return a 2-tuple with the actual port values, or return a named tuple or class instance.

### Implicit tuple unpacking

```
for (error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds)
```

can lose the parens.

### Imports

To abbreviate your code, do some `from x import y`:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from itertools import zip_longest
```

Comment: Those are some nice suggestions but the `is_file_valid ` has to return something since it's used in one of `parser.add_argument`s params. I'd also love to hear some other suggestions regarding the structure of the whole project :)

Comment: _is_file_valid has to return something_ - Sure; I've edited my answer

Comment: _I'd also love to hear some other suggestions regarding the structure of the whole project_ - use a helper class for named parse elements; edited